# How to format values in a flask dynamic table

Tags: javascript

I pull data from an API, in the ETL process, I convert them to plain numbers without any formatting so the formulas can execute.

But, I want the data to show back converted into currency results once called in the front-end table.

This is the dynamic table render:

```
<!-- Equity Holdings Performance Table -->
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Trade Date</th>
            <th>Price Gain</th>
          </tr>
          {% for row in all_equity_data_html %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{row.equity_id}}</td>
            <td>{{row.equity_date_purchase}}</td>      
            <td> &#x24; {{row.equity_price_gain}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

This is the conversion script that works on one field but not on a dynamic table:

```
<script>const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2
})
  formatter.format(row.equity_price_gain)
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
  $("td.equity_price_gain").each(function() { $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).text()).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})); })
  })
</script>
```

How to fix the below script? (I did try two variants to see if I can get it another way)

[image: Non-formatted table]

Comment: in your 2nd script tag, `$` is missing as a typo or is it not present in the code itself? in `("td.equity_price_gain")`

Comment: @sudipto-roy it was a type, I updated the code as shown above but still nothing happens

Comment: there is no `td` in your html having css class as `.equity_price_gain`. `$("td.equity_price_gain")` will be empty. Is that also a typo?

Comment: @SudiptoRoy I don't have "td" in my HTML table because I use dynamic flask call values.
How should I update the JS code to make it aligned, please?